# Identifying elements using xpath and cssSelector w/ Javascript

Tags: javascript, selenium, xpath, protractor, ui-automation

So most of my experience is in Java/Selenium. I normally would do something like..

```
By loginButton = By.xpath("//a[text(), 'Login']");
```

or something like that. What would the syntax be for Javascript? Something like..

```
var login = element(by.xpath("//a[text(), 'Login']"));
```

Is this accepted? The app uses AngularJS but theres not always a good identifier to use.

Answer (score 0):

Compared to Java, Protractor has an additional locator to locate an element by CSS and text:

```
element(by.cssContainingText('a', 'Login'))
```

But in your case, the element is an anchor, so you should use by.linkText :

```
element(by.linkText('Login'))
```

Comment: Okay, what about an element like ui-sref="elem"? How could I use the css to get it by a value rather than text?

Comment: by attribute `ui-sref`: `element(by.css('[ui-sref="elem"]'))` or by value: `element(by.css('input[value="whatever"]'))`